# Touchpad suddenly stopped working (Ubuntu 18.04)

Tags: 18.04, touchpad, thinkpad

Today (9.Feb) I ran the Ubuntu software updater, and rebooted my Thinpad X1 carbon (6gen) (standard Ubuntu 18.04.1 (xorg); kernel `4.15.0-45-generic`).

After that, my touchpad stopped working. That is, the mouse cursor is unresponsive; the only thing that actually works is pressing the left "mouse" button on the trackpad. However, it seems that from time to time (I don't recognize a pattern) the touchpad gets responsive for a second or two. In rare cases, it seems to go back to full functionality, but once I reboot, it's unresponsive again. My external bluetooth mouse works fine.

Does anyone know what might have gone wrong, and how I could fix this?

**EDIT:**
For some reason, disabling the trackpoint in the BIOS-settings did the trick, the touchpad is usable again. However, it "feels" a bit different, and I notice that I cannot "click & drag" anymore.

Comment: When the touchpad is unresponsive, can you post the last few lines after running `dmesg` in a terminal? Maybe the error messages from the `dmesg` output can help pinpoint a solution quicker.

Comment: 'dmesg' gives me the following error messages: `psmouse serio2: Failed to reset mouse on synaptics-pt/serio0`, `thermal thermal_zone6: failed to read out thermal zone (-61)`, `psmouse serio2: Failed to enable mouse on synaptics-pt/serio0`

Comment: i just ran `dmesg` again, now it gave me  `psmouse serio1: TouchPad at isa0060/serio1/input0 lost sync at byte 1`  several times, followed by  `psmouse serio1: issuing reconnect request`, `psmouse serio1: synaptics: queried max coordinates: x [..5678], y [..4758]`, `psmouse serio1: synaptics: queried min coordinates: x [1266..], y [1094..]` and `psmouse serio2: Failed to reset mouse on synaptics-pt/serio0`

Answer (score 1):

My touchpad issues were always related to the version of the kernel.
With 4.15 my touchpad is not responsive at all. with 4.19 works just fine. with 4.20 buggy.

Is there any chance that your update affected the kernel you use?

down or upgrading your kernel might solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

The latest updates upgraded the kernel to 4.15.0-72-generic. But it has issues with Synaptics touchpad drivers and all of sudden after the restart, the touchpad stopped working. So downgraded to 4.15.0-70 and my touchpad started working again.